# Tetris shifting 2D array

Tags: c++, tetris

I'm currently writing a tetris in C++ and I am at the last stage, I need to delete a row when it is full. Once a piece falls it is stored in a boolean array **grid[20][10]**. For example I check which row is full (or **true**), if it is I call a method **deleteRow**, where **n** is a number of row:

```
void Grid::deleteRow(int n)
{
  for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
   {
     grid[n][j] = false;
   }
}
```

Once the row is deleted I call a method moveRowDown:

```
void Grid::moveRowDown()
{
  for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
   {
    for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
     {
       grid[i+1][j]=grid[i][j];
     }
  }
}
```

So this method does not work, and all of the pieces disappear. I know I am missing the logic. Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They disappear because you copy 1st empty row to 2nd, then to 3rd and etc.
You need to rewrite your first loop in Grid::moveRowDown() to work from the bottom of a glass:

```
for (i = HEIGHT-2; i>=0; i--)
```

Comment: It works! I understand the logic now! Thank you very much for your time! Thank you!

Comment: Also consider a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of rows rather than a 2D array. vector practically does all of the work for you.